# ngGrid client side paging

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, ng-grid

I cannot figure out why the paging controls (client side) for my ng Grid aren't working.  The controls simply don't fire any noticeable event, and the control that determines the page number, if you click on it many times, exceeds the number of pages there should be.  The data is brought into the grid fine, but it's just the paging that's broken.  Anyone experience similar problems?

js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
//service call to ge the data
app.service('MyService',function($http){
   var get = function(){
       return $http.get('data.json');
   }
    this.get = get;
});


//controller where the grid is supposed to live
app.controller('NewController',function($scope,$http,MyService) {
    $scope.data =[];
    $scope.columns=[]
    $scope.filterOptions = {
        filterText:'',
        useExternalFilter: false
    }
    $scope.pagingOptions ={
        pageSizes: [5,20,30],
        pageSize: 5,
        totalServerItems: 21,
        currentPage: 1
    };

    $scope.myOptions = {
        data: 'data',
        columnDefs: 'columns',
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
        enablePaging: true,
        showFooter:true,
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
        showFilter: true
    };



    MyService.get('data.json').success(function(thisData){
        $scope.data = thisData;
        var columnHeadings = $scope.data[0];
        for(var prop in columnHeadings){
            $scope.columns.push({
                field: prop,
                displayName: StringUtils.splitCamelCase(prop)
            });
        }

    })
});

<html ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Getting Started With ngGrid Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ng-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/ng-grid-2.0.11.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
   <script src="Utils/StringUtils.js"></script>
    <style>
        .gridStyle {

            width: 600px;
            height: 500px
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body >


<div ng-controller="NewController">

    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="myOptions"></div>
    <div>
        <select ng-options="size as size.name for size in sizes " ng-model="item" ng-change="update()"></select>
        {{item.code}} {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>




</body>
<script>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the paging manually inside of your controller and calculate the max like this

```
$scope.maxPages = function(){
    data=Math.round($scope.pagingOptions.totalServerItems/$scope.pagingOptions.pageSize);

    return data;
};
```

Comment: it's only for geting maxpages but not set in ng-grid pagination option

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `$scope.getPagedDataAsync` and  `$scope.setPagingData` methods for the paging buttons to work.

Take a look at Server-Side Paging [Example](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid)